# Is it safe to calculate confidence interval on normally distributed ln(x) and convert the confidence interval to x by calculating e^x?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, mean, logarithm

Lets say that i have a skewed variable x, that have a non-normal distribution. I want to calculate mean and confidence interval for x but confidence interval assumes normality. So i take natural logarithm of x (ln(x)) and ln(x) becomes normally distributed. Does it make sense to calculate mean and confidence interval on ln(x) and convert those point estimates to x-space by taking exponent of those (mean,upper confidence level, lower confidence level)?

Comment: Yes____________

Comment: $\exp(\overline{\log X}) \not = \overline{X}$ (the geometric mean is usually not equal to the arithmetic mean)